# Microsoft Graph "messages" delta request truncates too many results with date filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I think I've found a bug with the date filtering on the delta API.

I'm finding on one of the email accounts I'm working with using Office 365 Graph API that the "messages" graph API delta request is returning a different number of items than are actually in a folder for the expected time range. There are 150,000 items covering 10 years in the folder but delta only returns the last 5,000-ish items covering the last 60 or so days.

## Paging Works Fine

When querying the graph API for the folder "Inbox" it has 154,045 total items and 57456 unread items.

```
IUserMailFoldersCollectionPage foldersPage =
                await client.Users[mailboxid].MailFolders.Request().GetAsync();
```

I can skip over 10,000, 50,000 or more messages using paging.

```
model.messages = await client.Users[mailboxid].MailFolders[folderid].Messages.Request().Top(top)
                    .Skip(skip).GetAsync();
```

## Delta with Date Filter doesn't work

But when looping with nextToken and deltaTokens, the deltaToken appears after 5000 or so email messages. Basically it seems like it's only returning results for the last couple months even though the filter is saying find messages for the last 20 years.

Here is the example for how we generate the Delta request. The time is hardcoded here but in reality it is a variable.

```
var sFilter = $"receivedDateTime ge {DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(-20).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}";
model.messages = await client.Users[mailboxid].MailFolders[folderid].Messages.Delta().Request()
                    .Header("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=" + maxpagesize)
                    .Filter(sFilter)
                    .OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc")
                    .GetAsync();
```

And then on each paging operation I do the following. "nexttoken" is either the next or delta link depending on what came back from the first request.

```
model.messages = new MessageDeltaCollectionPage();
                model.messages.InitializeNextPageRequest(client, nexttoken);
                model.messages = await model.messages.NextPageRequest
                    .Header("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=" + maxpagesize)
                    .GetAsync();
```

## Delta without Filter works

If I do the exact same code for delta above but remove the "Filter" operation on date, then I get all the messages in the folder.

This isn't a great solution since I normally only need messages for the last year or 2 years and if there are 15 years of messages it is a huge waste to query everything.

## Update on 12/3/2019

I'm still getting this issue. I recently switched back to trying to use Delta again whereas before I was querying everything from the server even though I might only need the last month of data. But that's super wasteful.

This code works fine for most mailboxes but sometimes I encounter a mailbox with this issue.

My code looks like this.

```
string sStartingTime = startingTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss") + "Z";

var messageCollectionPage = await client.Users[mailboxsource.GetMailboxIdFromAccountID()].MailFolders[folder.Id].Messages.Delta().Request()
                                .Filter("receivedDateTime+ge+" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sStartingTime))
                                .Select(select)
                                .Header("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=" + preferredPageSize)
                                .OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc")
                                .GetAsync(cancellationToken);
```

At around 5000 results the Delta request just stops returning results even though there are 66K items in the folder.

Comment: Hi Paul, can you replicate this with other users mailboxes? Or is it this particular user?

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT I only saw this on one mailbox I was working with. I had lots of other Office 365 accounts that didn't have this issue. In the end I just queried all the emails to do the sync.

Comment: OK if this still is an issue please hit me up here.

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT I just encountered this again. I was able to verify that the emails are sitting in their Inbox and I can query for them using pagination but when I use Delta it only returns the last 4 months of emails.

Answer (score 1):

Paul, my peers confirmed there is indeed a 5000-item limit if you apply $filter to a delta query of the message resource. 
Within the next day, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages?#use-query-parameters-in-a-delta-query-for-messages) will also be updated with this information. Thank you for your patience and support!